# How to prevent div re-size on zoom?

Tags: html, css

My hamburger icon resizes, whenever the user zooms in or out.

Is there any way to solve this?

Maybe by changing the units in which the hamburger's width is set?

Note: The hamburger icon is not a picture but a collection of elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  touch-action: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
}

#header-background {
  background-color: #08599d;
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu-icon {
  resize: none
}
```

```html
<div id="header-background"/>
<svg id="menu-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z" fill="white"/></svg>
```

Comment: Like the problem is that the blue background remains fixed, but the hamburger icon resizes

Comment: margin-top pushes the entire blue background down

Comment: There is no margin-top in the code you posted. If you want us to help you you have to provide us with the minimal code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can't see the same design on jsfiddle that I can see on Chrome

Comment: All the bar(s) seemed to be stacked one over the other.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the ham burger icon.